# Getting undefined when call this.state = { key : this.props.xxx.id }?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

*I have 2 component App.js and EditUser.js.
in App.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    userEditObject: {}
  }
}
```

---

```
this.setState({
  userEditObject: user
})
```

---

```
user: {
  id: 1,
  name: "A",
  tel: "012",
  role: 1
}
```

---

```
...render(){
  <EditUser userEditObject={this.state.userEditObject} />
}
```

in EditUser.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    id: this.props.userEditObject.id,
    name: this.props.userEditObject.name,
    tel: this.props.userEditObject.tel,
    role: this.props.userEditObject.role
  }
}
```

When I `console.log(this.state)` in EditUser.js, it display
`{ id : undefined, name : undefined, tel : undefined, role : undefined }`

The goal is whenever `<input>` onChange, I will have state like this
`{ id: 1, name: "ABC DEF", tel: "123" , role: 1 }` and continue update.

What am I doing wrong?
This is full code of EditUser.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    id: this.props.userEditObject.id,
    name: this.props.userEditObject.name,
    tel: this.props.userEditObject.tel,
    role: this.props.userEditObject.role
  }
}
isChange = (event) => {
  var name = event.target.name
  var value = event.target.value
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  })
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={(event) => this.isChange(event)}
        defaultValue={this.props.userEditObject.id}
        name="id" type="text" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Id"
      />
      <input
        onChange={(event) => this.isChange(event)}
        defaultValue={this.props.userEditObject.name}
        name="name" type="text" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Username"
      />
      <input
        onChange={(event) => this.isChange(event)}
        defaultValue={this.props.userEditObject.tel}
        name="tel" type="text" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Điện thoại"
      />
      <select
        onChange={(event) => this.isChange(event)}
        defaultValue={this.props.userEditObject.role}
        name="role" className="custom-select">
        <option value={1}>Admin</option>
        <option value={2}>Mod</option>
        <option value={3}>Member</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't know where/when you call `setState({ userEditObject: user })` but your first render will most likely use `this.state = { userEditObject: {} }` from the constructor. Because `setState()` is async. That would be why you get `undefined` in all your fields

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your comment, `setState({ userEditObject: user })` is call in App.js , i've checked on ReactDevTool, userEditObject in App.js has all data from user 
Before EditUser.js render , i call constructor(props), this.state = { id : this.props.userEditObject .... }, but  it return undefined on ReactDevTool.

Comment: I don't think you're right. Try to initialize `this.state = { userEditObject: { name: "Not Loaded" } }` and check if this name shows up in your `<EditUser />` component. I'm most certain that there is a first `render()` that initializes `<EditUser />` before the `userEditObject` is set.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your suggestion,i know what the problem is.  I'm know searching for the solutions when i click the button, it re-render the child Component